# Is their any sklearn module like voting classifier for regression?

Tags: scikit-learn, regression, ensemble-learning

I used to use VotingClassifier(from sklearn) like below. And now I want to find ensemble for regression model.

```
model= VotingClassifier(estimators=[('svmc', best_SVMC), ('rfc', best_RFC), ('xgbc', best_XGBC),('mlpc', best_MLPC)], voting='soft', n_jobs=2)
```

Could you recommend ensemble model for regression?

note:

svmc = SVC()

rfc = RandomforestClassifier()

xgbc = XGboostClassifier()

mplc = MLPClassifier()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way. Someone answered in Kaggle.

Solution :

Simply make predictions and take an average of them.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#voting-classifier

For classification there are two ways:

hard voting - class which was predicted by most models is selectes;

soft voting - each model predicts probabilities, classes with the highest 
probability are chosen.